# PHP se ve página en blanco si está en línea pero si lo abro en MAMP si se muestra ¿por qué?

Tags: php

hace unos días subí al servidor un proyecto web que utiliza de php y noté que justo la sección donde lo utilizo aparece en blanco, al igual que las secciones html que le siguen. Sin embargo cuando abro el archivo en MAMP (mi sistema operativo es Windows) dicha sección si se muestra, al igual que las que le siguen.

No entiendo porqué sucede, creo que puede ser algún signo (sobrante o faltante) en el código. Ya configuré el archivo php.ini para que se muestren los errores pero no me arroja ninguno. Dejo mi código y el cómo se ve la página en línea vs localhost.

**Código**

```
 <main class="seccion contenedor">
        <h2 class="fw-300 centrar-texto">Lo más vendido</h2>

        <?php
            try {
                require_once('bd_conexion.php');
                $sql = " SELECT * FROM `lo_mas_vendido` ";
                $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        ?>

        <div class="contenedor-anuncios">

            <?php while( $lo_mas_vendido = $resultado->fetch_assoc() ) { ?>

                <div class="anuncio">
                    <a class="producto-info" href="#producto<?php echo $lo_mas_vendido['id_producto']; ?>">
                        <img src="images/Productos/<?php echo $lo_mas_vendido['url_imagen']; ?>" alt="Imagen del producto">
                    </a><!--Colorbox -->    

                    <div class="contenido-anuncio">
                        <h3><?php echo $lo_mas_vendido['modelo_producto']; ?></h3>

                        <ul class="iconos-caracteristicas">
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/Iconos/<?php echo $lo_mas_vendido['icono_1']; ?>" width="45rem" alt="Ícono reparación, servicio y refacciones">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/Iconos/<?php echo $lo_mas_vendido['icono_2']; ?>" width="45rem" alt="Ícono garantía">
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <!--div>
                            <a class="producto-info boton boton-amarillo d-block" href="#producto<//?php echo $lo_mas_vendido['id_producto']; ?>">Ver Producto</a>
                        </div--> <!--Botón con Colorbox -->

                        <!--Colorbox -->
                        <div style="display:none;">
                            <div class="producto-info" id="producto<?php echo $lo_mas_vendido['id_producto']; ?>">
                                <img src="images/Productos/<?php echo $lo_mas_vendido['url_imagen']; ?>" alt="Imagen del Producto">
                                <h2><?php echo $lo_mas_vendido['nombre_producto']; ?></h2>
                                <p><?php echo $lo_mas_vendido['descripcion_producto']; ?></p>
                            </div><!-- producto-info --> 
                        </div> 

                    </div> <!--contenido-anuncio-->
                </div> <!--anuncio-->
            <?php } ?><!--while-->   
        </div> <!--contenedor-anuncios-->   

        <div class="ver-todos">
            <a href="http://olinko.com/cgi-bin/online/storepro.php" target="_blank" class="boton boton-verde boton-ver-todos">Ver Todos</a>
        </div>
    </main>
```

**Como se ve el código en mi editor (uso VS Code con el tema Monokai Dimmed). Los colores de los símbolos señalados son diferentes y no entiendo porqué. Pienso que podrían estar marcando un error de sintaxis.**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Como se ve en el servidor**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Como se ve en MAMP**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme.
Gracias.

Comment: Qué versión de php tienes en el servidor y cuál en local?

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. En el localhost la versión es 7.2.10 y en el servidor 7.1.

Comment: Un "truco" que utilizo para saber en qué lugar se quedó mi código es revisar cual fue el último elemento del DOM que apareció y luego lo busco en el código para ver hasta qué código PHP llegó. Me explico?

Comment: Yo diría que se trata más bien de que no hay elementos qué mostrar, tal vez la base de datos no contiene registros o la conexión a la misma no es correcta... asegúrate de eso.

Comment: Lo de los colores distintos es porque un código php está dentro de las comillas y otro fuera

Comment: @MatíasRodríguez Efectivamente, la página en línea sólo me carga un header del main y ya. Mientras que el localhost carga todo el contenido de ese main junto con la sección que el sigue y el footer. Muchas gracias por tus respuestas, verificaré la conexión a la base de datos y continuo en contacto por aquí.

Answer (score 0):

quizás tengas mal las rutas de los estilos y de las imágenes. Presiona F12 para ver si te salen errores de recursos no encontrados en la consola. También podrías revisar que el nombre de esos recursos esté escrito bien, ya que si tu hosting tiene LAMP, es case sensitive

Comment: Creo que esto debería de ser un comentario para retroalimentar y sugerir soluciones.

Comment: No me salen errores pero he notado que el tema de VS que uso (Monokai Dimmed) me marca algunas llaves, paréntesis y comas  en naranja, otras en blanco y otras en verde. No entiendo por qué. Creo que puede estarme indicando in error en la sintaxis pero no encuentro cual. Reeditare mi pregunta para agregar la imagen y puedas ver a lo que me refiero.